# Catching unhandled exception in Intellij IDE [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, exception, intellij-idea

Is there any way to catch unhandled exceptions in compile time in Intellij IDE (or some other way ?)

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(1,2)
    println(list.first())
}
```

As you can see `list.first()` throws an exception (if the list is empty), but I don't get any warning in the IDE to handle it properly. I already tried [Csense plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12673-csense--kotlin-checked-exceptions) but unfortunately no luck. I'm not sure how much work it takes to achieve this stuff, I have looked at Intellij [PSI element](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/psi-elements.html) to know if is there any way to recursively trace the function call and to catch some unhandled exceptions, but it's not straight forward as I thought :)

It would be great if someone share the details if they already achieved this in their kotlin project.

**Note**:
The reason I asked this question is that I'm working on a project which uses kotlin [arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/) lib to make the code more functional style. So they use [Either](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/-either/) to handle errors explicitly instead of try/catch.

Comment: Almost any function can throw a runtime exception. How will you determine which ones you would want to check? You'd have to create a database of them, I think, and then write lint rules At some point, it's clearly not worth it because your code will be saturated with try/catches and become nearly unreadable.

Comment: [Almost any function can throw a runtime exception.] not pure functions example fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a+b I don't think this will throw a runtime exception, isn't it?

Comment: @Vencat the same function with `/` instead of `+` can throw an `ArithmeticException`, and it is not really less pure

Comment: @Vencat why are you trying to catch all those exceptions in your code? The very definition of `first()` is to crash if there is no element, otherwise you would use `firstOrNull()` if you needed to handle this case. The point of those exceptions is to detect programming errors in a way that can be investigated, but you shouldn't try to catch them all

Comment: @Joffrey exactly, here I need to use firstOrNull() to handle exceptions without try/catch but in a big code base we are calling a lot of standard functions like first() and we forgot to write code to handle the exception. In this case, it would be nicer if IDE or some other tool tells the programmer that you forgot to handle exceptions here and your code has the possibility to crash at runtime.

Comment: What you are essentially asking for is checked exceptions in java. It was an explicit design decision to not have checked exceptions, because it forces you to handle certain exceptions while in some cases you don't need to. Handle the exceptions you want to handle instead of forcing a framework to tell you to handle all checked exceptions for you. You need to determine if you can recover from that exception. if you can you probably want to handle it, else just let it crash

Comment: *exactly, here I need to use firstOrNull() to handle exceptions without try/catch* - @Vencant why do you think you need to do that here? You might want to fail on empty lists because another invariant ensures it's not empty. You certainly don't want to handle it in several places. There is unfortunately no difference between a programmer that "forgot the list could be empty and called `first()` anyway" and a programmer that just relies on the exception to bubble up in the case where the list is empty. It seems to me that you want to bring back Java's checked exceptions as Daniel said.

Comment: Either we need to treat errors as values like Golang and Rust or force the exception handling like Java. This hidden stuff is painful in some situations. Anyway, it is what it is.

Comment: This would be a lot more extreme than Java’s checked exceptions because it would check all kinds of exceptions, including all the ones that are due to programmer error. I don’t think it’s practical. You might have checked elsewhere in your code that the collection is not empty, but you would have to redundantly deal with the null case that can never happen by using `firstOrNull()` everywhere just to satisfy the lint check.

Comment: See also related issues https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18276, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-10948

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov Omg! it was created 5 years before but no update.